# How to deal with Case Sensitivity in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, unique-constraint, check-constraints

I have a master table for color codes which stores various unique color values. It has a column Color_value on which UNIQUE constraint has been applied. However it is accepting both 'Black' and 'black' values. How can such situations be handled?

Comment: I'd specify a case insensitive collation for the column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a unique index like this:

```
create unique index unique_color_value on colors(lower(color_value));
```

That said, it would be much simpler to make your data consistent from the start, by using a constraint that allows only lower case values in the column to start with.

```
create table colors (
    ...
    color_value text 
        unique 
        check(color_value = lower(color_value))
)
```

Comment: If I put the Unique check during the table creation, am I not restricting data entry only for lower case values then?

Comment: @Kartikeya: yes, that’s my point. Then you don’t need to worry about the case anymore later on.

Comment: Okay, but if I need to maintain Case Sensitivity in order to show data as it is in my application, will it work that way?

Comment: @Kartikeya: in that case, use the unique index I suggest at the beginning of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be a unique index as detailed by GMB's answer.

The other options are:

- Use the `citext` extension (**c**ase **i**nsensitive **text**) and use the `citext` data type. Then you can use a simple unique constraint.
- With PostgreSQL v12 or better, create a case insensitive ICU collation:

  ```
  CREATE COLLATION german_ci (
     LOCALE = 'de_AT@colStrength=secondary',
     PROVIDER = 'icu',
     DETERMINISTIC = FALSE
  );
  ```

  That example is for Austrian German, use the language of your choice or use `und` for a language agnostic collation (as far as such a thing exists).

  Then define the column as `colname text COLLATE german_ci UNIQUE`, using a regular unique constraint.